# Create an empty object or array from a complexType

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Knowing I have some complexType defined in a wsdl I can access through SOAP via http://www.example.com/webservice?wsdl and that this web service does declare complexType like this (this is only a snippet of the wsdl) :

```
<xsd:complexType name="customer">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="address" type="typens:address" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="address">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="postcode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Is there an easy way via SOAP in PHP to create an empty array or object which will be an instance of this complexType ?

The expected behaviour is to have then

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'firstname' => null
  public 'lastname' => null
  public 'address' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'street' => null
      public 'city' => null
      public 'postcode' => null
      public 'country' => null
```

Or

```
array (size=3)
  'firstname' => null
  'lastname' => null
  'address' => 
    array (size=4)
      'street' => null
      'city' => null
      'postcode' => null
      'country' => null
```

I had a look to [SoapParam](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapparam.php) and [SoapVar](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php) documentation, but they both lack of a proper documentation so I can not seems to figure out if those do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project on Github that aims to resolve this same exact issue.

Check out [WSDL2PHPGenerator](http://wsdl2phpgenerator.github.io/wsdl2phpgenerator/) and see if it does what you want (the project is alive and kicking and has about 3000 installations in the last month alone, so I think it is a safe bet). According to its page it takes a WSDL file and outputs class files ready to use.

Hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the information, although, I'm more looking to have some kind of standard object directly from the complexType. To be fair, my goal is not to lazily create classes, but to have an object which can still be accurate if the third party company working on the webservice does decide to add datas in it without prompting me first.
Still worth a +1 :)

Comment: Well, I must have misunderstood then, sorry about that! Without me knowing the specifics of your case, I do not think you'll need such a tool that automatically maps to new service versions as they are released to the public. If the team creating the service is anywhere near adequate, they will implement new versions of the service without breaking the contract with existing consumers (e.g. by making the new fields optional, or releasing a different version of the service altogether, while keeping the old one). So you will have to add new fields only if you need to use new functionalities.